# How to send Python proxy objects across TCP

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I've having problems sending proxy objects across a TCP connection with Python 3.7.3.  They work fine locally, but the authentication keys don't get set right when the two processes interconnect with TCP.

The story goes like this: I have an instance of a class on one process and I want to refer to it from another process on a different machine.  So I create my `BaseManager` on the first process with `address=('', 50000)`, pull out a copy of its `_authkey`, and tell the other process to create a `BaseManager` with `address=('whatever', 50000)` along with `authkey=...` and call `connect()`.  So far, so good.

The first process has a few things registered:

```
BaseManager.register('ManagerClass', ManagerClass)
BaseManager.register('managers', callable = lambda: managers)
```

`managers` is just a dictionary.  `ManagerClass` has a method that saves a self-proxy in the dictionary, created like this:

```
def autoself(self):
    server = getattr(multiprocessing.current_process(), '_manager_server', None)
    classname = self.__class__.__name__
    if server:
        for key,value in server.id_to_obj.items():
            if value[0] == self:
                token = multiprocessing.managers.Token(typeid=classname, address=server.address, id=key)
                proxy = multiprocessing.managers.AutoProxy(token, 'pickle', authkey=server.authkey)
                return proxy
    else:
        return self
```

Incidentally, if I try to store the `ManagerClass` object directly in the dictionary and then transfer it, I get

```
TypeError: can't pickle _thread.lock objects
```

No great surprise - it's a complicated object and probably has thread locks in there somewhere.

So, I store the self-proxy created with `autoself` into the dictionary and transfer it.

It almost works, but the `authkey` doesn't get set right on the receiving end, so it doesn't work.  Looks like the `authkey` gets set to the local process's `authkey`, because that's the default in `AutoProxy` if no `authkey` or `manager` is specified.

Well, how would it be specified?  The dictionary is represented by a proxy object, which calls the remote method `items()`, which returns a pickled `RebuildProxy` containing an `AutoProxy`.  Should `RebuildProxy` figure out what manager it's being called from and pick out the `authkey` from there?  What if the returned proxy object refers to an object on a different process than the one holding the dictionary?  Don't know.

I've "fixed" this by hacking `BaseProxy`'s `__reduce__` method to always transfer its `authkey`, irregardless of `get_spawning_popen()`, and disabling the check in `AuthenticationString` that prevents it being pickled.  Look in Python's `multiprocessing/` directory to make sense out of what I'm talking about.

Now it works.

Not really sure what to do about it.  What if we've got a complicated setup with multiple processes passing proxy objects around?  No reason to assume that a process receiving a proxy object has an authkey for the process that manages the object; it might only have an authkey for the process *sending* the proxy.  Does that mean we need to pass authkeys around with proxy objects?  Or am I missing a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a simple way to fix my problem: use the same authentication key for every process on every machine.

Just set the key first thing when I import multiprocessing:

```
import multiprocessing
multiprocessing.current_process().authkey = b"secret"
```

No need to change the standard library code.